# Inspecting first row

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

In SSRS 2008 I have 10 columns, and the data is grouped up based on column one (lets call it employee number), and has multiple rows in each group, ordered by a weekly date with the most recent week is at the top.
In column 10 of the group header row, I would like to check if column 10 on the first row contains the value 1 and if so, set a red box/indicator in that header column 10. If any of the other rows below the first contain a 1 then return amber otherwise remain uncoloured.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please add information as to how the groups are formed and what the naming of each layer are.

Comment: Hi Jacobm001, I'm unsure what a layer is. The groups are formed based on a value of column 1, which as mentioned we are calling Employee Number. Also mentioned is that all the rows in each grouping is organised by date with the most recent at the top. I'm unsure what else needs to be added to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [FIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-first-function) function in the `expression` field of the `BackgroundColor` property?

Comment: Hi Cool_Br33ze, I have been trying to use FIRST but with no success. For example I'm doing =IIF(First(Fields!COLUMN10.Value, "RTRReportData") = 1, "Red", "White") to get red if the first row contains a 1, otherwise set it as white. but it produces nothing.

Comment: Perhaps you need to change `1` to `TRUE`... Is it a bit field?

Comment: Thanks bJones, I just tried this but it didn't seem to make a difference. I tried adding similar FIRST() code to the text box expression and I notice it doesn't appear to pull in the value of the group below it, so I am suspecting it's just pulling in the first value of the entire dataset rather than per group :(

Comment: @Rob Is "RTRReportData" the name of the dataset or group?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze That is the name of the dataset (there are multiple). thanks.

Comment: That should work,  Can you update your Q with pictures showing the amendments you've made?

Comment: Thanks @Cool_Br33ze, your last question put me on the right path to finding the colution. I have altered the "RTRReportData" to now be the name of the group, and this is giving me the answer I need in the First() function.   Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help